# Entity Framework Core - getting related data

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having some problems explicitly loading related data on a particular relationship.

The classes in question are defined as follows:

```
public abstract class Wallet
{
    #region Database Properties
    [Key]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;        
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    public List<WalletTransaction> WalletTransactions { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class UserWallet : Wallet
{
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class WalletTransaction
{
    #region Database Properties
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Wallet")]
    [Required]
    public string WalletId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(28,18)")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    public Wallet Wallet { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

I am then trying to get a particular instance of Wallet, including the `WalletTransactions` here:

```
public static UserWallet GetById(string id)
{
        using (var db = EthereumWalletDbContextFactory.Create())
        {
            var wallet = db.UserWallets
                .Single(f => f.Address == id);                

            db.Entry(wallet)
                .Collection(c => c.WalletTransactions)
                .Load();

            return wallet;
        }
}
```

What I am getting is an instance of Wallet, that contains 0 transactions. I have run a profiler on the SQL Server and confirm that there is no attempt to even look up the `WalletTransactions`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the below code. `var wallet = db.UserWallets`
                `.Single(f => f.Address == id)`
    `.Include(x => x.WalletTransactions)`

Comment: did try that earlier, and again just now ... same result. For the moment as a workaround, I am populating the WalletTransactions manually, which is working, but clearly not as designed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. Can you file a new issue with repro steps (including sample data) at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore